# Python/Pandas: Converting numbers by comma separated for thousands

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column containing long numbers. I am trying to convert all the values in the numbers column to comma separated for thousands.

```
df

col_1      col_2
Rooney     34590927
Ronaldo    5467382
John       25647398
```

How do I iterate and get the following result?
Expected result:

```
col_1      col_2
Rooney     34,590,927
Ronaldo    5,467,382
John       25,647,398
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use string formatting,

```
df['col_2'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col_2'].fillna(0), errors='coerce')    
df['col_2'] = df['col_2'].map('{:,.2f}'.format)
```

Do remember that the col_2 now will be string not integer.

```
    col_1   col_2
0   Rooney  34,590,927.00
1   Ronaldo 5,467,382.00
2   John    25,647,398.00
```

Comment: I vote for this one! Map imo is much faster than apply in general.

Comment: I tried: 
`df['col_2'] = df['col_2'].astype(int).map('{:,.2f}'.format)`

Got an error: `ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '34,590,927'`

Comment: What is the output of df.dtypes?

Comment: `col2    float64`
`dtype: object`

Comment: I tried the edit. Unfortunately it gives me an error:
`ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer`

Comment: I get this: `to_numeric() got an unexpected keyword argument 'downcast'`

Comment: There is a NaN value in the col_2 causing this error. Try this: df['col_2'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col_2'].fillna(0), errors='coerce')

Answer (score 5):

apply format function to col_2

```
df = df.assign(col_2=df.col_2.astype(int).apply('{:,}'.format))

     col_1       col_2
0   Rooney  34,590,927
1  Ronaldo   5,467,382
2     John  25,647,398
```

Comment: I got the following error:
ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
----> 1 df = df.assign(col_2=df.col_2.apply('{:,}'.format))
      2 df

/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   2218         else:
   2219             values = self.asobject
-> 2220             mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   2221 
   2222         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/src/inference.pyx in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas/lib.c:62658)()

ValueError: Cannot specify ',' with 's'.

Comment: @Rooney you did not post full trace

Comment: @Rooney what is the type of col_2? you may need to convert the col_2 to int

Comment: The 'col_2' is probably integers. I am storing the Count(*) from a SQL query in col_2.
How do I convert it to string in one line?

Comment: Good attempt - but this could get slower for large data frames.

Comment: @galaxyan: 
It still gives me an error: 
ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '34,590,927'

Comment: @Rooney did you alrady changed the col_2?

Comment: Yes, I tried `df = df.assign(col_2=df.col_2.astype(int).apply('{:,}'.format))`

Answer (score 0):

```py
d = len(list(df.columns))
```

i.e `d=22`

`d = d-2` and we want to convert only 20 columns

```py
for x in df.columns[-d:]:
     df[x] = [(locale.format("%d", a, grouping=True)) for a in df[x]]
```

This will solve the problem and dynamically make it comma separated.