# Pandas Python: one-liner to print all relevant columns with comma thousands separator?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a Pandas DataFrame like:

```
    m1       m2
0   24899    24899
1   15       1
```

Is there an easy one-liner that allows automatic formatting with a comma thousands separator? Looking for:

```
    m1       m2
0   24,899   24,899
1   15       1
```

I've seen multi-line solutions or solutions that use lambda functions applied to Series objects that have to be manually specified. Ideally, I'm looking for a dynamic, general solution that would work for a DataFrame with mixed `dtypes`. Worst case, a solution for the toy example above without having to specify each variable name in my DataFrame.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46677613/8601641) might be useful.

Comment: `df.apply(lambda x: x.agg('{:,d}'.format) if x.dtype=='int64' else x)`

Answer (score 0):

How about this

df['m1'] = df['m1'].map('{:,}'.format)

df['m2'] = df['m2'].map('{:,}'.format)