# Convert float64 to a string with thousand separators

Tags: pandas

I have a Population Estimate series with numbers as float64 and I need to convert them to a string with thousands separator (using commas). Using all significant digits (no rounding).
e.g. 12345678.90345 -> 12,345,678.90345

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python/Pandas: Converting numbers by comma separated for thousands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46677550/python-pandas-converting-numbers-by-comma-separated-for-thousands)

Answer (score 0):

Try applying a comma-float string formatter.

```
population = population.apply('{:,.5f}'.format)
```

Comment: thanks. it only partially works. I have numbers with different sets of significant figures after the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired formatting, you could use `'{:,}'.format`.
This will use commas as thousands separator and only output the values that are in your data and not clip or fill to a certain number of digits.

```
data = data.apply('{:,}'.format)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column with formatted string values:

```
   df["PopEst"] = df["Population"].map('{:,}'.format)
```